# Stop Grails compilation from showing dots

Tags: grails, maven-2

Is there a configuration option, command line parameter, or a property that would stop Grails compilation from being cute and showing the growing trail of dots for operations that take time? It does so by sending "\r" to console and printing the previous line with another dot appended. It looks ok but still a little flashy when the compilation runs in console but it looks ugly in automated builds (see below). I wonder if there is a way to tell it not to print the progress indication. Thank you!

```
 [exec] [INFO] | Resolving plugin JAR dependencies
 [exec] [INFO] | Resolving plugin JAR dependencies.
 [exec] [INFO] | Resolving plugin JAR dependencies..
 [exec] [INFO] | Resolving plugin JAR dependencies...
 [exec] [INFO] | Resolving plugin JAR dependencies....
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `--plain-output` switch? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails does offer a switch on the console/command line to remove the dots from the output (and a few other *fancy things*). It's called `--plain-output` and it can be used as such:

```
grails prod war --plain-output
```